Visual Studio adding 0 inside parenthesis, like "(0)"
My Visual Studio is adding 0 inside parenthesis. This started a while ago and still occurs (in version 17.12.3).
For example: if I type .ToList() then Visual Studio turns it into .ToList(0).
Another case: if I type .First() then Visual Studio turns it into .First(0).
But this doesn't always occur, sometimes it works as expected and displays .ToList() (or .First()).
I've tried at intelliSense but couldn't solve this.

That's very strange. Don't rule out that it could be a hardware problem (i.e., your keyboard).

Is it a fresh install, or is there any modules / extensions added ?

@topsail this occus at Visual Studio only, doesn't occur at other softwares I daily use

@Pac0 I do have some extensions (all Microsoft): Live Share 2022 (recently installed); Microsoft Library Manager; ML.NET Model Builder 2022. The Visual Studio itself is installed since ~Fev/2024.

@topsail the bahaviour may occur in other cases, like from First() to First(0). I've made an update to the answer.

I'd recommend disabling completely all the extensions, then try to reproduce the issue. If you can still reproduce, let us know. If you can't, then re-enable extensions one by one, trying to reproduce after each activation.

also, can you provide a screenshot of the screen just at the moment the "0" appears ? It may be a simple "suggestion" (should be in a lighter shade color than actual written code). Some suggestions options could appear with Ctrl + Alt + Space or in the setting - editor -autocompletion menu (something like that)
